# How many devices we can connect to bluetooth 5

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, iot

How many devices can we connect to the **Bluetooth 5** and can get info about the total no. of Bluetooth within that signal?

Which devices can help to do it.

Answer (score 8):

For classic Bluetooth the limitation is 7 connections and this has been the case since before Bluetooth 5 was released. For Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE), there is no limitation on the number of connections, and that is purely dependant on the hardware's/stack's capabilities. The Bluetooth specification does not put a limit on the number of connections for BLE, and therefore the theoretical maximum depends on Bluetooth-related timings (namely connection interval and connection supervision timeout).

For a more detailed answer about the number of connections. please see the link below:-
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39174115/2215147

I hope this helps.

Comment: Where did you get 2 billion connections from? That's impossible since they all need one connection event at least every 32 seconds. But you can't fit those many packets in the air during that time.

Comment: I've misplaced the 2 billion connections comment, that should've been before the Bluetooth-related timings restriction. 2 billion comes from the fact that a BLE packet's Access Address is 32 bits, therefore 2^31 = ~2billion, but you're right, this is not possible because of the connection supervision timeout. I have modified my comment to reflect that.